# ViewPager like playstore

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to make viewpager work like one in google playstore in movies,music,books section.

Below is screenshot of one:

[image]

This is screenshot of viewpager i want:

[image]

below is my xml code:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/vp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

below is java code:

```
  ViewPager vp;
    int mResources[]= {R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d};
    vp = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vp);
    vp.setPageMargin(-10);
    vp.setAdapter(new ViewPageAdapter(ViewPagerActivity.this,mResources));
```

below is xml for single item:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#eee"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="220dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:elevation="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/c"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Indeed the first screenshot contains a viewpager but the second screenshot is only a horizontal scrollview. So what you want is probably just a horizontal scrollview.

Comment: second is part of first screenshot only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, you want a ViewPager whose next/previous items partly showing.

If so, set minus page margin to the viewPager by `ViewPager.setPageMargin(int)`, and add (positive) margins to each item's left and right.

I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager with a horizontal orientation. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733221/android-horizontal-recycler-view-scroll-direction) should answer your question. ViewPager is typically used in conjunction with entire fragments as opposed to scrolling components within those fragments according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).