# How to create slider image with incaditor as a list of images on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout

I need to do this UI same this image as below:
Currently I don't know how to create it.  I need some examples or some existing library or some keywords to refer to, so anyone who has created a layout like this can help me suggest them.

[image]

Comment: use recycler view in android using horizontal scroll
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733221/android-horizontal-recyclerview-scroll-direction

Comment: Are you using XML Views or Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you mean. However, to make an image slider like that, try using RecyclerView in horizontal orientation. For example:

XML :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_only"
        tools:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/your_item_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Activity :

```
rv_horizontal = findViewById(R.id.horizontal_only)
rv_horizontal.apply {
  layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false)
  setHasFixedSize(true)
  yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
  adapter = yourAdapter
}
```

Don't forget to set your adapter to list on RecyclerView.